# Scala Play: Invalid '@' symbol in email regex

Tags: regex, scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to put an input regex that uses the `pattern` attribute to insure a valid username (the `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,12}$` portion in the regex's below) OR email is entered in my Scala Play template. With Play templates, the `@` is used to indicate a break from HTML and that "Scala goes here", so when I have my input line and try to include the @ used in emails. It complains:

> Invalid '@' symbol

I've tried:

1. Doing it normally
2. Triple quotes, no escape character before the `@`
3. One escape character before the `@`
4. Two escape characters before the `@` (with and without triple quotes)

   pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,12}$|/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/"

   pattern="""^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,12}$|/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/"""

   pattern=^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,12}$|/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/"

   pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,12}$|/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/"

Any ideas?

(EDIT Ugh Sorry, SO won't show stuff wrapped in `input` tags, and it also won't let me format the above as code, so I had to add just the pattern="..." after my original post without formatting as such, apologies.)

Comment: Try doubling `@`: `@@`. Else, try `\u0040` or `\x40`.

Comment: The double @ sign worked. If you add it as an official answer, I'll give you the check mark and you can have the sweet sweet points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping `@` in Scala Play template can be performed by doubling the symbol.

Use `@@` to introduce a literal `@` into the pattern.

However, since you are using a regex here, note that a hexadecimal [`\u0040` or `\x40`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%40#title) might also be used (but only when the `\` is a literal, i.e. it should be escaped for a regex engine, like `"""\u0040"""`, so that Scala does not parse it as a Unicode char).